# Update record if parameter has a value - SQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My current code updates all values, and if there is an empty parameter it updates the corresponding field on the table to null. I want to update only the fields that have a value.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE drinks SET
    name        = :name,          // Mojito -> Update it
    description = :description,   // Lorem ipsum.. -> Update it
    glass_id    = :glass_id,      // NULL -> do not update
    video_url   = :video_url      // NULL -> do not update
    WHERE id = '$drinkId'
";

try {
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $drinkName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);   
    $stmt->bindParam(':glass_id', $glassId);
    $stmt->bindParam(':video_url', $videoUrl);
    $stmt->execute();



// Close databse
$db = null;


} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Comment: You can add the following to the end of your query: ``AND glass_id IS NOT NULL AND video_url IS NOT NULL``

Comment: Why are you using parameters for every value EXCEPT `WHERE id = '$drinkId'` Use paramters for all values

Comment: You should replace `$drinkId` with a placeholder as well to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't want to update those 2 fields when they are empty.

this code check if a field is null and only when it is not null it will add the field to the query, also the same for binding the value.

```
$sql = 'UPDATE drinks SET';
$sql = sql . 'name = :name,';
$sql = sql . 'description = :description';

if (!is_null($glassId))
    $sql = sql . ',glass_id = :glass_id';

if (!is_null($videoUrl))
    $sql = sql . ',video_url = :video_url';

$sql = sql . ' WHERE id = :drinkId';

try {
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $drinkName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
    $stmt->bindParam(':drinkId', $drinkId);

    if (!is_null($glassId))
    $stmt->bindParam(':glass_id', $glassId);

    if (!is_null($videoUrl))
    $stmt->bindParam(':video_url', $videoUrl);

    $stmt->execute();

    // Close databse
    $db = null;


} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Comment: `how about this?` sounds more like a suggestion. Add more details on why this code should be used and why this will work. This will be helpful to OP and others who can learn from it, instead by just copying the right answer.

Comment: Well after a little configuration that code did the job! This is the idea. Thank you @MangaValk!

Comment: Glad to help :) @GiorgosKaryofyllis